# Php date() function gets wrong minutes... why?

Tags: php

I was working with a project in Php and I noticed that date (and time too) return wrong time.
At first it seemed the wrong timezone, but later I noticed that there is not one or more hours of difference (I'm working on localhost) with system clock, but about 28 minutes... That's weird.. what could it possibly be?

Comment: Can you share the code that displays the wrong time?

Answer (score 34, accepted):

If you're using "M" or "m" for minutes, then you're actually displaying month of year. "i" is used for minutes.

Comment: Aahhahahahah, I swear I've been laughing for 10 minutes, it was it :D

Comment: Is there a particular reason why "i" is used as such?

Comment: I can't believe I've been writing PHP professionally for 15+ years, and this STILL bites me in the ass ;-)

Comment: @gotch4 hahahaha, I swear I've been pulling my hair for 10 minutes - now I'm bold - ffs php - whyyyyy `i` for minutes?

Comment: i spent half a day to replace m with i, lol

Answer (score 3):

[PHP Date()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/intro.datetime.php) functions are based on the locale settings of the server, so I would make sure that the system current time is set correctly.

On a *nix system you can do the following:

```
# Check current time
$ -> date
Tue Mar  6 23:48:23 UTC 2012
```

If you are not using the correct timezone, you can do:

```
$ -> rm -f /etc/localtime

# You can use any timezone you wish, I prefer UTC
$ -> ln -sf /usr/share/zoneinfo/UTC /etc/localtime
```

If you need to correct your system time:

```
$ -> ntpdate -b pool.ntp.org
```

Comment: Thank you for your explanation.... but unfortunately it was the m instead of i...

Comment: Ahhh, at least it was an easy fix.