# strtotime PHP changing format

Tags: javascript, php, html, mysql

i'm currently having problem while changing format of a DATE in php.
I have store in mysql db "Tstart" in DATETIME format "YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS".

here is the code:

```
foreach ($book as $books) {
                    if ($dropdown['id'] == $books['idsala']) {
                        $time=strtotime($books['tstart']);
                        $startime=date('d/M H:m',$time);
                        echo '<a href="#" class="float-left">' . $books['tstart'] . '</a><br>';
                        echo '<a href="#" class="float-left">' . $startime . '</a><br>';}
```

but when i go to see the result on the page i have this output

```
2020-05-13 19:00:00
13/May 19:05
```

in the converted variable i find +5 minutes and i can't realize how is possible

Can someone help me?
Thanks you

Comment: You're using `m`instead of `i` to show minutes, so, you're getting month instead minutes.

Comment: Already closed, but could also be a dupe of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9593684/php-date-function-gets-wrong-minutes-why

Answer (score 2):

So for the date format. the small "m" represents months. you would wanna use as small "i"
PHP date - https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.date.php

```
$startime=date('d/M H:i',$time);
```

Comment: Thank you very much... i used moment.js for so much time and i didn't remember that in PHP "i" is for minutes